# Footer with it's own font color and size

Tags: css, footer

The page contains a table and footer. Although I use a separate font size in the #footer 6px, it's still adapting the font size of the table 13px bold. How can this be fixed?

The footer is in a separate div not inside the table.

```
<table width="400" border="0" style="margin: auto;"></table>
<div id="footer">Copyright 2013</div>
```

CSS

```
table { margin: auto; 
    font:bold 13px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}


#footer {
clear: both;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 6pt;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a markup problem in your page, i.e. You didn't close a tag properly. Is this all of your HTML?

Comment: Use a DOM inspector, and it'll tell you exactly where the styles being applied to any DOM element are coming from.

Comment: Do you have a minimum font-size set in your browser?  The provided code does not reproduce the problem:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/0isz6p62

Answer (score 0):

Did you try size: 6px? 
My CSS skills have diminished since I haven't used them in ages but play around with it. Also be sure to say 6px not 6pt.

Also, you could try putting any desired text (the copyright stuff) into a paragraph tag. That way you specify even further which tags you are targeting, i.e. #footer p {size: 6px;}

In your original post of the issue, you have font-size:6pt, try changing it to 6px. Does that help?

Comment: I tried 6px but the footer font still following the the table font of 13px.

Comment: Hm, did you try font-size: 6px? In what you originally posted you put font-size: 6pt, that may have been the issue.